# Creating new Columns and fill them based on another columns values

Tags: python, pandas, rename

Let's say I have a dataframe `df` looking like this:

```
|ColA     |
|---------|
|B=7      |
|(no data)|
|C=5      |
|B=3,C=6  |
```

How do I extract the data into new colums, so it looks like this:

```
|ColA  | B | C |
|------|---|---|
|True  | 7 |   |
|False |   |   |
|True  |   | 5 |
|True  | 3 | 6 |
```

For filling the columns I know I can use regex .extract, as shown in this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33415978/7727113).

But how do I set the Column name at the same time? So far I use a loop over `df.ColA.loc[df["ColA"].isna()].iteritems()`, but that does not seem like the best option for a lot of data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `str.extractall` to get the data, then reshape the output and `join` to a derivative of the original dataframe:

```
# create the B/C columns
df2 = (df['ColA'].str.extractall('([^=]+)=([^=,]+),?')
                 .set_index(0, append=True)
                 .droplevel('match')[1]
                 .unstack(0, fill_value='')
       )

# rework ColA and join previous output
df.notnull().join(df2).fillna('')

# or if several columns:
df.assign(ColA=df['ColA'].notnull()).join(df2).fillna('')
```

output:

```
    ColA  B  C
0   True  7   
1  False      
2   True     5
3   True  3  6
```

Comment: Hi, this looks good already. But if I have multiple columns in `df` then it sets all column values as 'True'. Could you also explain why you use `(~df.isnull())`? Thanks!

Comment: Then you can use `df.assign(ColA=~df['ColA'].isnull()).join(…)`, the `~` is to invert the result of `isnull` but one can actually use `notnull` ;)